# Auto Linking Words But Only One Time

Tags: text, customization

I highly need a piece of code which will replace a simple word with a hypertext link, using str_replace method. And fortunately I found this code below, but the problem is that it repeats the link with all matching keywords, whereas I want to add the link only once and forget other matching keywords.

For example, if it sees "nursery rhymes", replace it with a hypertext link, but do not add the link again with "nursery rhymes", "rhymes" or "poems" keywords on same page. One URL only one time.

I also heard that it's probably not possible with str_replace, but possible with preg_replace, which could limit the occurrence of replacements.

Please help. I am not very familiar with PHP or coding, so please use complete code, so I can simply copy and paste in my functions.php. Here is the code I am using:

```
function wp_affiliate_links($text) {
    $replace = array(
        ' nursery rhymes ' => ' <a href="http://www.nurseryrhymes.me/">nursery rhymes</a> ',
        ' poems ' => ' <a href="http://www.nurseryrhymes.me/">poems</a> ',
        ' rhymes ' => ' <a href="http://www.nurseryrhymes.me/">rhymes</a> ',
    );
    $text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
    return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wp_affiliate_links');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'wp_affiliate_links');
```

Comment: Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/using-str-replace-so-that-it-only-acts-on-the-first-match)

Comment: but I don't know how to use it Nilambar... Blue Clothes, I know meaning of your name, I also from Bharat....

Comment: Yes, Nilambar means Blue clothes :-) I am from Nepal BTW. Ok, have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you pass limit number of replacements in str_replace? Like that

```
$text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text, 1);
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry I was thinking about something else and missed this one. You can use preg_replace and set limit in it. Like this one.

```
function wp_affiliate_links($text){
    $replace = array(
        '/ nursery rhymes /' => ' <a href="http://www.nurseryrhymes.me/">nursery rhymes</a> ',
        '/ poems /' => ' <a href="http://www.nurseryrhymes.me/">poems</a> ',
        '/ rhymes /' => ' <a href="http://www.nurseryrhymes.me/">rhymes</a> ',
    );
    $text = preg_replace( array_keys($replace), $replace, $text, 1 );
    return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wp_affiliate_links');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'wp_affiliate_links');
```

**EDIT 2:**

Try this one.

```
function wp_affiliate_links($text){
    $replace = array(
        '/ nursery rhymes /' => ' <a href="http://www.nurseryrhymes.me/">nursery rhymes</a> ',
        '/ poems /' => ' <a href="http://www.nurseryrhymes.me/">poems</a> ',
        '/ rhymes /' => ' <a href="http://www.nurseryrhymes.me/">rhymes</a> ',
    );
    foreach ( $replace as $key ) {
        $text = preg_replace( array_keys($replace), $replace, $text, 1 );
        return $text;
    }
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wp_affiliate_links');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'wp_affiliate_links');
```

Comment: No it does not work, showing Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in .. * .. function.php on line 537

Comment: See edits. I used preg_replace for this.

Comment: Wow, but It is checking only keywords not url. I tell you how? It's Replacing all three keywords i.e. "nursery rhymes", "poem" and "rhymes" with hyperlink three times, whereas I want to add the link only once. **If once the keyword replaced with one link, ignore other keywords.**

Comment: Try edit 2 and let me know.

Comment: Actually it's exactly doing that. It's replacing each keyword once. And then move to other keyword.

Comment: No, not working... visit here to see `shayaris.punjabi.cc/rhymes-in-news`

yes, its replacing and moving to next keyword, but it should not replace next keyword, if once replaced with same url, if url is different, then it's ok, but not with same url.

Comment: Well, I am not sure if that can be done easily because you will have to check URL in array values too. I will let someone else help you with this.

Comment: I will be highly thankful of you for that Robert, I have nothing else to say Thank you very much, not even enough reputations to like your answers. I must when I will got.

Thank you again... waiting for solutions...